# Reduce historical time series by averaging over time intervals

Tags: mysql

I have a weather observation table with frequent entries - for simplicity let's consider just the temperature observations. The observations can be somewhat sporadic, but sometimes up to half a dozen occur in each clock hour interval. My goal is to run a procedure at, say, hourly intervals to find those historical hours that contain multiple temperature observations and find the average temperature and time and then to replace all those observations with the single averaged observation.

I have managed to compose a mysql query which creates an averaged temperature value for the hour interval (shown below) but am needing assistance to know how to take this one step further by actually replacing each hours observation entries with the single new average entry.

```
SELECT stationcode, AVG(temperature) as t_avg, COUNT(temperature) as t_count, FROM_UNIXTIME
(AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(obs_datetime))) as datetime_avg, MINUTE(obs_datetime) as minute, HOUR(obs_datetime) as hour, DAY(obs_datetime) as day, MONTH(obs_datetime) as month, YEAR(obs_datetime) as year
FROM obs_table
WHERE stationcode='AT301'
GROUP BY hour, day, month, year
HAVING count(*) > 1
ORDER BY datetime_avg DESC
```

I am imagining that the solution might involve a join or a temporary table. Can anyone provide any sample code or hints as to how I can go about this?

Adding following due to a request for the table structure:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `obs_table`
--

CREATE TABLE `obs_table` (
  `rec_id` bigint(12) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `stationcode` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `obs_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `temperature` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `temp_dewpt` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `rel_humidity` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `wind_dir_degs` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `wind_avg_kmh` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `wind_gust_kmh` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `pressure_hpa` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `visibility_m` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `icon` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Indexes for table `obs_table`
--
ALTER TABLE `obs_table`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`rec_id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `stationcode` (`stationcode`,`obs_datetime`);
```

Comment: I would have a boolean column in your table indicating that a row is averaged data.  Then you have two steps, inserting the average rows (using an INSERT....SELECT) and then deleting the rows they came from.

Comment: would be helpful if you showed your schema (output of `show create table obs_table`)

Comment: what are description and icon supposed to be for the averaged rows?

Comment: description is text description of weather conditions and icon is typically a word for which there is a corresponding pre-defined icon corresponding to those conditions

Comment: yes, but if you average three rows, what do you set those to in the new row?

Comment: they only change infrequently - it would be fine to simply use the first value in the hour, for example

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: 10.1.44-MariaDB-0+deb9u1